# Virtual canvas with at.js

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, interactive, ar.js, web-ar

I want to make a canvas plane with augmented reality on AR.js and A-frame, by the moment it doesn't work, it's only show the white plane and I can't draw on it. Please take a look to the code an comment any possible solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>AR.js y A-Frame: Dibujo en Realidad Aumentada</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.0.8/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <!-- Definir el marcador personalizado -->
      <a-marker
        preset="custom"
        type="pattern"
        url="https://cdn.glitch.global/69316176-f68c-453d-996f-0d56f38577a4/marker.patt?v=1685648515251"
      >
        <!-- Plano que servirá como lienzo virtual -->
        <a-plane
          position="0 0 0"
          rotation="-90 0 0"
          width="4"
          height="2.25"
          color="white"
          draw="color: black; brushSize: 10"
        ></a-plane>
      </a-marker>

      <!-- Cámara y luz -->
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
      <a-light type="ambient" position="0 5 0" intensity="0.5"></a-light>
      <a-light type="directional" position="2 4 -3" intensity="0.5"></a-light>
    </a-scene>

    <script>
      // Agregar un evento para permitir el dibujo al tocar la pantalla
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
```

Different points of view to solve the possible error on the code and sharing the solution to the community.